# Iterate over Point2Ds contained in a Line2D

Tags: java, line, point

I am having trouble with a fairly simple task, as the title says, i want to iterate over all points contained in a Line2D.Double. I tried googling, but couldn't really find anything. I am guessing it has something to do with the PathIterators?

Thank you in advance for your tips

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339328/iterate-through-each-point-on-a-line-path-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8145796/957654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Line2D.Double only has 2 points P1 and P2, the start and end of a straight line. You can get them with getP1() and getP2().

Do you actually want to iterate over a Path2D.Double? If so you would iterate over a path like this:

```
    PathIterator pathIter = path.getPathIterator(null);
    while(!pathIter.isDone()) {
        final double[] segment = new double[6];
        pathIter.currentSegment(segment);
        //do something with segment
        pathIter.next();
    }
```