# Find nearest point on a MKPolygon from a CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationcoordinate2d, mkpolygon

I have a series of coordinates which forms a MKPolygon. I have another coordinate say user location. Now I need to find the nearest point from the user location to the polygon to show the shortest distance from the user location to polygon. In my observations, there is no direct way to achieve this. Could some one help me find a solution for this in swift for iOS?

Comment: One possible way to do this is you may find the distance between two coordinates (Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance?changes=_4) and then find the smallest distance.

Comment: @SunilChauhan I need all coordinates of the polygon for this. I only have a polygon which was created with edge coordinates.

Comment: Oh, okay. This is not written in swift, but you will get the gist:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048284/1208191